# workerd devtools - enabling source maps

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am developing a Cloudflare worker using:

`wrangler dev src/index.ts --experimental-local --port 8701`

This runs `workerd` locally. I open the Chrome devtools by pressing `d` from the terminal.

I have two issues:

1. All `console.log` entries reference the JS bundle name/line number (not the original source).
2. No code is available from the `Sources` tab.

Can source maps be enabled or is this just not supported?

I know wrangler uses `esbuild`, which supports inline source maps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

to enable source maps with wrangler dev, you need to make sure that your TypeScript compiler generates the necessary source map files. In your `tsconfig.json` file, ensure that you have the following option set:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Once you've confirmed that your TypeScript compiler is generating source map files, you can configure wrangler to use them by adding the `generate_source_map` flag to your `wrangler.toml` file:

```
[dev]
generate_source_map = true
```

With the generate_source_map flag set to true, wrangler dev will generate and serve the source map files along with the JavaScript bundle when running the worker locally.

Comment: Thanks, but `generate_source_map` does not seem to be mentioned anywhere in the docs - do you have a reference? How did you discover this key?